# Install window forms application on Mac os

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

I have developed a window forms application using visual studio 2017.
Now I want to install this window forms application on Mac os.
Please help in this connection. What easy possible way to do.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to solve this problem? Did you install visual studio under macos and recompile the code for macos? That seems like the best approach to this. Have you tried that?

Comment: You can almost all information from https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complete app in WinForms on .NET Framework, you could try porting it to Mono, which is .NET Framework implementation for Linux and MacOS. You can check out this [link](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/).

It's a completely different story if you're running .NET Core. In that case I would suggest creating web UI in ASP.NET Core. Or if you're familiar with one of UI frameworks compatible with MacOS (e.g. Qml.Net or AvaloniaUI), build the frontend in it.

Comment: "porting it to Mono" is impossible today, as Mono WinForms is a 32 bit only implementation and Apple no longer allows 32 bit apps on latest macOS.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello,** First at all winform are designed to run on windows only(BTW is really old technology of creating desktop application using C#). Much better approach is to use WPF.
In case of You want run Your application on different platforms is much better to use WPF on .NET CORE. The same application You can easy run on:

Windows, Mac OS, Linux

I hope this can help You.

Comment: thank you for help I try to create App in WPF. Can you tell me how to install/deploy this App created in WPF .NET Core to mac. Thanks

Comment: Remember to select WPF via .NET Core, not .NET Framework version.

Comment: It is really hard to tell which is better, WinForms or WPF. Anyway, you didn't answer what to use on Mac.